# Java Projectile Angles

Tags: java, trigonometry, angle

So, I'm making a platformer where you should be able to drag your mouse to launch a projectile from your character in the direction of the mouse release, with a velocity of the distance between the two points.

```
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    player.setAiming(true);
    Point2D.Float aimpoint = new Point2D.Float(e.getXOnScreen(), e.getYOnScreen());
    player.setAimpoint(aimpoint);
    player.setAimDistance(GetDistanceToPoint(player.getPos(), aimpoint));
}
public static float GetAngleOfLine(Point2D.Float p1, Point2D.Float p2) { 
    double xDiff = p2.x - p1.x; 
    double yDiff = p2.y - p1.y; 
    System.out.println("P1X: " + p1.x + " P1Y: " + p1.y + " P2X: " + p2.x + " P2Y: " + p2.y + " Angle: " + Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(yDiff, xDiff)));
    return (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(yDiff, xDiff));
}
public static float GetDistanceToPoint(Point2D.Float p1, Point2D.Float p2){
    float distance = (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p2.y - p1.y, 2) + Math.pow((p2.x - p1.x), 2));
    return distance;
}
```

And then, when the mouse is released,

```
player.setAimingangle(GetAngleOfLine(player.getPos(), player.getAimpoint()));
```

And then a projectile is created, where angle is player.aimingangle and strength is player.aimingdistance:

```
        float yvel = (float) (strength * Math.sin(angle));
    float xvel = (float) (strength * Math.cos(angle));
```

I'm getting incredibly weird projectiles, which are flying everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Math.sin` and `Math.cos` take radians arguments, but you're feeding them degrees.